# VBA Loop to next visible cell

Tags: excel, vba

This is doing my head in now and I cannot seem to get it right, I basically want to loop through column AJ and then if it contains anything like School, it stamps "School" in Column A, however I have a filter on the data because I only need to do this to certain rows..

This code currently returns an error but i believe I am on the right track with it... Just need a pointer if possible please

Open to options on this to make things more efficient as I am a bit of a newbie at this.. I effectively need to make loads of filters and conditions so I will be repeating this code multiple times because we output different files based on the bucket column

Below is my revised code which is now working

```
Sub Bucket_macro()
Dim rFiltered As Range, rng As Range, c As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

'Insert Bucket Column
Range("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Value = "Bucket"

Range("Q:Q").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("Q1").Value = "Age"

'add formula for DOB
Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("$Q$2:$Q" & Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("C1048574").End(xlUp).Row & "").Formula = "=IF($O2="""","""",DATEDIF($O2,TODAY(),""Y""))"

'filter to NewID only
Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("$A$1:$BQ" & Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("C1048574").End(xlUp).Row & "").AutoFilter Field:=66, Criteria1:="New ID"


lastrow = Range("C1048574").End(xlUp).Row

'first condition based on occupation field
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("AJ2:AJ" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each c In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'   c.Select
   If c.Value = "" Then
   'do nothing
   
   Else
        Select Case True
                
            Case (c.Value Like "*school*")
                c.Offset(0, -35).Value = "School"
            
            Case (c.Value Like "*nursery*")
                c.Offset(0, -35).Value = "School"

            Case (c.Value Like "*university*")
                c.Offset(0, -35).Value = "School"
                
            Case (c.Value Like "*university*")
                c.Offset(0, -35).Value = "School"
            
            Case (c.Value Like "*education*")
                c.Offset(0, -35).Value = "School"
                
            Case (c.Value Like "*college*")
                c.Offset(0, -35).Value = "School"
        End Select
    
    End If

Next c

'Next condition based on age
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("Q2:Q" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each c In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'   c.Select
   If c.Value = "" Then
   'do nothing
   
   Else
        Select Case True
                
            Case (c.Value < 19)
                    c.Offset(0, -16).Value = "School"
                    
            End Select
    
    End If

Next c

'Next condition based on job.description
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("AN2:AN" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each c In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'   c.Select
   If c.Value = "" Then
   'do nothing
   
   Else
        Select Case True
                
            Case (c.Value Like "*school*")
                c.Offset(0, -39).Value = "School"
                
            Case (c.Value Like "*academy*")
                c.Offset(0, -39).Value = "School"
                
            Case (c.Value Like "*college*")
                c.Offset(0, -39).Value = "School"
                
            Case (c.Value Like "*university*")
                c.Offset(0, -39).Value = "School"
                
            Case (c.Value Like "*nursery*")
                c.Offset(0, -39).Value = "School"
                    
            End Select
    
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: "returns an error" does not say too much. It can help only if you specify what error and on which code line... `Dim rFiltered, rng, cl As Range` declares everything `As Variant` and only `cl As Range`. Try `Dim rFiltered As Range, rng As Range, cl As Range` firstly...

Comment: I believe it was on line Set rng = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("AJ2:AJ" & lastrow).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) However I added .rows and it seemed to fix it, however the code still isnt doing what I want it to

Comment: Again, "still isn't doing what I want it to" is not enough. If you need help, you must tell us what it does against what you need...

Comment: I added rng as range and that fixed the above code, but it doesnt appear to be stamping in the School field based on the offset I have told it, it dont appear to be looping through each cell however im not sure. Code completes but doesnt actually change anything except from the filter and adding the column

Comment: I have fixed it, nevermind it was simple I just needed to add c.select prior to my conditional statements

Comment: Selecting, activating are not necessary, except in some cases when they cannot be avoided. Please, try to eliminate `c.Select`and use `c.Value` instead `ActiveCell.Value`.

Comment: Selecting, activating only consume Excel resources without bringing any benefit...

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess in a loop scenario like this its unavoidable as you need to tell it to go to the next active cell

Comment: No! Categorically it is not! It is simple to verify this. Try my suggestion and check if it works.

Comment: Hmm it doesnt seem to work in my scenario how I have done my code... I am not sure how to post my revised code here

Comment: You can simple edit your code and paste the revised code to the end. But let me look a little to it. Please, comment `Range("A:A").Select` and the next line should be: `Range("A:A").Insert Shift ...`

Comment: Ok I have added my revised code now which works, I will add the Range("A:A") insert parts too as thats an easy change, I am not sure I will need the select first row in filtered data set part anymore

Comment: I cannot see anything from what I suggested in your "revised code"... It may work like a charm without any selection! `Range("A:A").Insert Shift ...` (and comment `Range("A:A").Select`) `Range("Q:Q").Insert Shift ...` (and comment `Range("Q:Q").Select`), comment `c.Select` and replace all `ActiveCell.Value`/`ActiveCell.Offset` with `c.Value`/`c.Offset`.

Comment: Yes sorry I added the Range("").Insert parts after I edited my post. C.offset doesnt work I tried this as it treats every condition as true

Comment: This cannot be true. I am not sure that you know what you are doing, no offence... Now I have to leave my office. If you would post a really revised code, I could show you where you made the mistake, or mistakes...

Comment: Ok I will add this a bit later on

Comment: Ok so I made the changes to the code and posted it above, I believe it works (I must have done something different earlier when I said it didnt work) it runs a lot quicker... I assume thats due to not doing c.select everytime?

Comment: I guess there is probably a neater way to write all the case statements, but im not sure. I guess you could use arrays based on x amount of case statements so they are all grouped together, just an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you’re at the early stages of your VBA learning, I think we can all remember what that was like.  There’s a number of observations and suggestions worth mentioning about your code.  I’ve provided an alternative below with comments explaining what certain different parts are for etc.

There’s nothing wrong with using a `Case…` approach, or even an `If..Else If` method.  I’ve taken a slightly different approach in an effort to reduce the number of lines of code needed.

I’m not sure I like your overall approach – once you start inserting columns in a  module that references specific columns, you can only run the code once – lest you end up in a very confused state.  It was a bit tricky following your references as it was, and you may need to make some adjustments to suit.  You don’t turn the filter off at the end of your module – so I didn’t either.

It works for me, let me know how you go with it.

```
    Option Compare Text '<~~ to ignore case in text comparisons
    Option Explicit     '<~~ to force declaration of all variables
    Sub Bucket_macro()
    'Declare all variables used
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, LastRow As Long, i
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet 1")              '<~~ change to whatever you called sheet 1
        
    ws.Range("A:A").Insert                      '<~~ insert both columns
    ws.Range("Q:Q").Insert                  
    
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Bucket"             '<~~ add headings
    ws.Range("Q1").Value = "Age"
    
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ get last row early
    
    'Add age formula
    With ws.Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC15<>"""",DATEDIF(RC15, TODAY(),""Y""),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    'Set filter on column BN to "New ID" only 
    ws.Range("BN:BN").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="New ID"
    
    'First condition: based on Occupation
    For Each c In ws.Range("AJ2:AJ" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        For Each i In Array("school", "nursery", "university", "education", "college")
            If InStr(c.Value, i) > 0 Then ws.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = "School"
        Next i
    Next c
    
    'Second condition: based on age
    For Each c In ws.Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If c.Value < 19 Then ws.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = "School"
    Next c
    
    'Third condition: based on job description
    For Each c In ws.Range("AN2:AN" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        For Each i In Array("school", "academy", "college", "university", "nursery")
            If InStr(c.Value, i) > 0 Then ws.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = "School"
        Next i
    Next c
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I can understand most of it and I do prefer it to my method. I am a little confused by the Next i parts as I do not see that you defined i as a variable. Can wildcards also be used?

Comment: In a Dim statement, a variable that isn't followed by a "as ..." defaults to type Variant. You'll see "i" at the end of the Dim statement in this case.

Comment: I also need to add a filter to column A to filter blanks so that the code doesnt overwrite itself as I will be putting the conditions on a hierarchy basis... So I'm not sure how to do that, and I also need to turn off autofilter mode which I can do easily

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. At what point in the code's execution do you want to filter for blanks/non-blanks in column A?

Comment: So after each Next C section basically

Comment: also, I just tested this and it works fine. Are the parts in the array already treated as if they are wildcards?

Comment: I'm still not quite getting your aim. Each of your 'conditions' results in placing the same value in column A: "School". What difference does it make if School is overwritten with School? What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry I didnt really make it clear in my initial post. There will be a few more conditions than just School hence not wanting to overwrite, I just thought I would post this and then I can repeat for the other conditions

Comment: Regarding your comments re wildcards - no. What happens is that the exact string (e.g. "nursery") is searched for in the (possibly larger) string in columns AJ and AN - sort of the opposite of using wilcards in your Case approach:)

Comment: Ah ok thats denoted by the InStr(c.value, i) parts I assume

Comment: OK, I  get you now! The way I would do it would be to add an 'AND IF' condition to the line 'If InStr...' before the 'Then' to check whether the cell in column A was blank or not.

Comment: Ok I will test and come back to you if I do not get it fully correct the way I am going to do it is probably like AND IF c.value = "" THEN .....

Comment: `And If ws.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = "" Then` would be the addition to use.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but when I add that it comes up the error "Expected Expression" this is the line "If InStr(c.Value, i) > 0 And If ws.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = "" Then ws.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = "School""

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out, just need to use AND instead of AND IF as its already enclosed within the if statement